# Htaccess redirect with query

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issue with a query string, although I'm not sure what i'm tryign to do is possible.

I have the following url with a search query attached: 
subdomain.mysite.com/search/?search=searchquery

but I need it to redirect to the following url including the query string:
subdomain.mysite.com/search/?rs=searchquery

I was wondering if this is possible with a mod_rewrite?

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/search/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.mysite.com/search/?rs=% [L,R=301]
```

I don't know if my Syntax is incorrect or i'm just barking up the wrong tree. Any help would be awesome.

This is the Start of my HTAccess File - This is a Wordpress site with the rewrite rule provided by user: Amine Hajyoussef:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/search/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search/?rs=%1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately this doesnt appear to work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the `1` after `%`, i have also changed the search string so it can be anything instead of just number.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/search/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search/?rs=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Amine, Sorry i clicked enter and didnt realise that submitted my comment, i've updated my main post. Thanks so much for getting back so quickly!

Comment: Nevermind, I've just added your fix to the top of my Htaccess file and it worked! thank you!